# How to get auto completion on jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am new to Python language programming. I found that we can have auto completion on Jupyter notebook. I found this suggestion:

"The auto-completion with Jupyter Notebook is so weak, even with hinterland extension. Thanks for the idea of deep-learning-based code auto-completion. I developed a Jupyter Notebook Extension based on TabNine which provides code auto-completion based on Deep Learning. Here's the Github link of my work: jupyter-tabnine.

It's available on pypi index now. Simply issue following commands, then enjoy it:)

pip3 install jupyter-tabnine,
jupyter nbextension install --py jupyter_tabnine,
jupyter nbextension enable --py jupyter_tabnine,
jupyter serverextension enable --py jupyter_tabnine"

I did 4 steps installation and it looked installed well. However, when I tried using Jupyter notebook its auto completion didn't work. Basically my question is please help how to get auto completion on Jupiter notebook? Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you activate the tabnine extension in you nbextension tab at jupyter home?

Comment: Yes I did. but it didn't work still

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing Nbextensions, go to Nbextensions in jupyter notebook, tick on Hinterland. Then reopen your jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 3):

Press `tab` twice while you are writing your code and the autocomplete tab will show for you. Just select one and press `enter`

Comment: I managed to get autocompletion by pressing the tab button once after reinstalling anaconda. yet, I want to get auto completion automatically without pressing tab button